Использование jaxws-maven-plugin с несколькими wsdl файлами с одинаковым portType
Использую com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin плагин в спринг-проекте, в конфигурации указано только ссылки на wsdl файлы
Обрабатываю несколько wsdl файлов, два из них используют одинаковый targetNamespace и portType.
Из-за чего плагин перезаписывает пакет и web service интерфейс.
Пытался настроить jaxws.xml таким образом, но получаю ошибку связанную с отсутствием portType в том или ином wsdl
<bindings xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxws">

    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='Client1']">
        <class name="Client1WebService"/>
    </bindings>

    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='Client2']">
        <class name="Client2WebService"/>
    </bindings>

</bindings>

Я зашел в тупик в решении данной проблемы. Прошу помочь
